# TOP, SUM SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table called `RPT` with the following columns:

1. `CODENUMBER`
2. `AXSUBGROUP`
3. `ITEMSTRUCTURE`
4. `UNITSSOLD`
5. `DOLLARS`

I need to return to the user the `TOP 20 AXSUBGROUPS` based on `UNITSSOLD` along with the `UNITSSOLD` and `DOLLARS` values. In addition, I need to return the `ITEMSTRUCTURES` that belong to these top 20 `AXSUBGROUPS` (joined by codenumber), along with their `UNITSSOLD` AND `DOLLARS`.

I'm not sure which way to go about querying this as I need to group by `AXSUBGROUP` and then by `ITEMSTRUCTURE` but `ITEMSTRUCTURE` is tied to `aXSUBGROUP` by `CODENUMBER`.

I'd appreciate any help you can give.

Thank you.

EDIT
To better illustrate my needs:

1. BAR - 10,000

   - BAR 2 oz - 5,000
   - BAR 1 oz - 5,000
2. GIFT BOX - 8,000

   - TRUFFLE BOX - 5,000
   - ACRYLIC BOX - 3,000

...

Here's sample data in the table (sorry - couldn't figure out how to format a table...)

```
CodeNumber UnitsSold Dollars AxSubGroup ItemStructure
ABC123    |    9    | 500   | Bar      | 1 oz
ABC456    |    9    | 800   | Bar      | 2 oz
ABC789    |    9    | 500   | Bar      | 3 oz
DEF123    |    3    | 200   | Tin      | Round
DEF456    |    2    | 200   | Tin      | Rectangular
GHI123    |    1    | 200   | Truffle  | Luxe
GHI456    |    5    | 100   | Truffle  | Executive
GHI789    |    4    | 200   | Truffle  | Eco
JKL123    |    9    | 500   | Box      | 2 pc
JKL456    |    5    | 100   | Box      | 4 pc
JKL789    |    5    | 100   | Box      | 8 pc
```

...
If it helps, originally this was 2 tables - RPT (CodeNumber, UnitsSold, Dollars) and FLEX (CodeNumber, AxSubGroup, ItemStructure).

Comment: Yes. (Originally not - created a temp for simplicity)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense - it seems that you have a single table, so what exactly do you mean by *joined by codenumber* ?? Is there a second table involved? What does that table look like?? So is each `AxSubgroup` unique in your table, or do you have lots of duplicates?? (also, side-note: these ALL UPPERCASE column names make reading and understanding your stuff REALLY hard.... I would recommend using more readable names like `AxSubgroup`, `UnitsSold` and so forth.....)

Comment: I need to get only the ITEMSTRUCTURES that made up the UNITSSOLD of the top 20 AXSUBGROUPS, where the UNITSSOLD is by CODENUMBER. Sorry if I'm not explaining well..

Comment: @marc_s: Codenumber is unique. AxSubgroup is not.

Comment: I THINK what you are looking for is the equivalent of a group_concat in SQL Server 2005.  You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005 to see if that gets you close.

Comment: @BrianHoover: The ItemStructures don't necessarily need to be concatenated or on the same row as the AxSubGroup. It's just a matter of pulling up the correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      RPT.CodeNumber
    , RPT.AxSubgroup
    , RPT.ItemStructure
    , RPT.UnitsSold
    , RPT.Dollars
    , grp.TotalUnitsSold
FROM 
      RPT
  JOIN
      ( SELECT TOP 20 
              AxSubgroup
            , SUM(UnitsSold) AS TotalUnitsSold
        FROM
              RPT 
        GROUP BY
              AxSubgroup
        ORDER BY
              TotalUnitsSold DESC
      ) AS grp
    ON 
      grp.AxSubgroup = RPT.AxSubgroup
ORDER BY
      RPT.AxSubgroup
```

Comment: Thank you! This one was the first I tried, since it looked the simplest, although I'm sure the others would work the same. (Wish I can mark all of them as answer :P) Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's ROW_NUMBER to the rescue!

```
SELECT CODENUMBER
    , AXSUBGROUP
    , ITEMSTRUCTURE
    , UNITSSOLD
    , DOLLARS
FROM
(
    SELECT CODENUMBER
        , AXSUBGROUP
        , ITEMSTRUCTURE
        , UNITSSOLD
        , DOLLARS
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AXSUBGROUP ORDER BY UNITSSOLD DESC) AS r
    FROM RPT
) a
WHERE r <= 20
```

Comment: Good call.  I was just about to click submit.  I had practically the same thing typed up.

Comment: :D  Yeah, that function is crazy useful.

Comment: @Norla: Your query returns more than 20 AxSubgroups.

Comment: @Becky How many rows do you get?  ROW_NUMBER should be limited to the value in the WHERE clause.  Since there's a PARTITION on AXSUBGROUP, there should be exactly 20 unique values.  Check syntax please.

Comment: @Norla: I'm getting 52 AxSubgroups. I test that by querying SELECT DISTINCT AXSUBGROUP FROM (your query here)- same number as distinct AxSubgroups in RPT table.

Comment: Would you like me to post some sample data in RPT?

Comment: I see where my query is wrong.  You'll need to post data from the source table in the question.  I had made an (evidently) incorrect assumption about the data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Need a better example of the expected output matching the sample source data. There remains quite a bit of ambiguity with the question. But here is another stab at it:

Using the sample source data with 4 "AxSubGroup" items ("Bar", "Tin", Truffle", "Box"), this solution restricts to the  top 3 AxSubGroups (rather than the top 20).

The "top" subquery sums "UnitsSold" for each "AxSubGroup", orders them in descending order, numbers them, and grabs the top 3. Here is the result before the last entry gets shaved off:

```
 axsubgroup | totalsold | rownum
------------+-----------+--------
 Bar        |        27 |      1
 Box        |        19 |      2
 Truffle    |        10 |      3
 Tin        |         5 |      4
(4 rows)
```

This set is then joined back to the original RPT table to get the details for each one of these top axsubgroup items.

```
CREATE TABLE rpt(CodeNumber varchar(6), UnitsSold int, Dollars int, AxSubGroup varchar(32), ItemStructure varchar(32));

INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('ABC123', 9, 500, 'Bar', '1 oz');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('ABC456', 9, 800, 'Bar', '2 oz');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('ABC789', 9, 500, 'Bar', '3 oz');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('DEF123', 3, 200, 'Tin', 'Round');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('DEF456', 2, 200, 'Tin', 'Rectangular');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('GHI123', 1, 200, 'Truffle', 'Luxe');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('GHI456', 5, 100, 'Truffle', 'Executive');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('GHI789', 4, 200, 'Truffle', 'Eco');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('JKL123', 9, 500, 'Box', '2 pc');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('JKL456', 5, 100, 'Box', '4 pc');
INSERT INTO rpt VALUES('JKL789', 5, 100, 'Box', '8 pc');


WITH top AS (

     -- Top AxSubGroups based on UnitsSold with order number assigned, restricted to top 20
    SELECT AxSubGroup, totalSold, rowNum
      FROM (
             -- Top AxSubGroups based on UnitsSold with order number assigned
             SELECT AxSubGroup, totalSold
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY totalSold DESC) AS rowNum
               FROM ( 
                      -- Top AxSubGroups based on UnitsSold
                      -- (do you really want this 'UnitsSold' or rather on 'gross': 'UnitsSold' * 'Dollars'?)
                      SELECT AxSubGroup, SUM(UnitsSold) AS totalSold
                        FROM rpt r
                        GROUP BY AxSubGroup
                        ORDER by totalSold DESC
                    ) x
               ORDER BY totalSold DESC
           ) y
      WHERE rowNum <= 3
)

SELECT t.AxSubGroup, t.totalSold, r.ItemStructure, r.UnitsSold, r.Dollars
  FROM top t
      ,rpt r
  WHERE r.AxSubGroup = t.AxSubGroup;

 axsubgroup | totalsold | itemstructure | unitssold | dollars
------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------
 Bar        |        27 | 1 oz          |         9 |     500
 Bar        |        27 | 2 oz          |         9 |     800
 Bar        |        27 | 3 oz          |         9 |     500
 Truffle    |        10 | Luxe          |         1 |     200
 Truffle    |        10 | Executive     |         5 |     100
 Truffle    |        10 | Eco           |         4 |     200
 Box        |        19 | 2 pc          |         9 |     500
 Box        |        19 | 4 pc          |         5 |     100
 Box        |        19 | 8 pc          |         5 |     100
(9 rows)
```

The first two columns of the result are summary/total columns which are repeated for each member of the group, while the last three columns are the details which comprise the sum.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like you need to:

1. Calculate group totals.
2. Rank groups by the totals.
3. Get the details of the groups that are in the top 20 UNION the groups that are in the top 20.

So maybe something like this:

```
;
WITH RPT (CodeNumber, UnitsSold, Dollars, AxSubGroup, ItemStructure) AS (
  SELECT 'ABC123', 9, 500, 'Bar'    , '1 oz'        UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC456', 9, 800, 'Bar'    , '2 oz'        UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC789', 9, 500, 'Bar'    , '3 oz'        UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF123', 3, 200, 'Tin'    , 'Round'       UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF456', 2, 200, 'Tin'    , 'Rectangular' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GHI123', 1, 200, 'Truffle', 'Luxe'        UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GHI456', 5, 100, 'Truffle', 'Executive'   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GHI789', 4, 200, 'Truffle', 'Eco'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JKL123', 9, 500, 'Box'    , '2 pc'        UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JKL456', 5, 100, 'Box'    , '4 pc'        UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JKL789', 5, 100, 'Box'    , '8 pc'
),
totals AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    TotalUnitsSold = SUM(UnitsSold) OVER (PARTITION BY AxSubGroup),
    TotalDollars   = SUM(Dollars  ) OVER (PARTITION BY AxSubGroup)
  FROM RPT
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalDollars DESC, AxSubGroup)
  FROM totals
)

SELECT
  rnk,
  AxSubGroup,
  ItemStructure,
  UnitsSold,
  Dollars
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk <= 3

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
  rnk,
  AxSubGroup,
  NULL,
  TotalUnitsSold,
  TotalDollars
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk <= 3

ORDER BY rnk, AxSubGroup, ItemStructure
```

The results are:

```
rnk  AxSubGroup  ItemStructure  UnitsSold    Dollars
---  ----------  -------------  -----------  -----------
1    Bar         NULL           27           1800
1    Bar         1 oz           9            500
1    Bar         2 oz           9            800
1    Bar         3 oz           9            500
2    Box         NULL           19           700
2    Box         2 pc           9            500
2    Box         4 pc           5            100
2    Box         8 pc           5            100
3    Truffle     NULL           10           500
3    Truffle     Eco            4            200
3    Truffle     Executive      5            100
3    Truffle     Luxe           1            200
```